# webapi error Multiple actions were found that match the request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an accountcontroller that has 2 actions here are the declarations:

```
HttpResponseMessage PostAccount([FromBody] Account account)
public HttpResponseMessage PostLogin([FromBody]string email,[FromBody] string pass)
```

Running in fiddler, I am receiving the error Multiple actions were found that match the request. Im a little confused on whats going on. Should I make two controllers just for Login and Register? is that standard practice.

Answer (score 3):

You can only have one parameter that comes from the body in Web API. If you want multiple things in the body, you should wrap them in a container class.

The error you're getting is happening because you have two actions that start with "Post". You can either create separate controllers, which makes sense if you're posting different types of entities. Or you can use action-based routing and create a route that looks like this:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("ActionBased", "{controller}/{action}");
```

to distinguish between the two actions when you POST.

Comment: Thank you. Does the same rule apply to PUT, GET, and DELETE? Example GetData(string name) and GetInformation(string title)

Comment: You can have GetData and GetInformation work fine without action-based routing as long as the parameters are different. So it should work. You would just get to Data by doing a GET for Account?name=foo and get to Information with Account?title=bar